# Does a point-to-point ethernet connection need a crossover cable?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have heard mixed answers regarding this question. I think historically the answer is "yes", but modern ethernet controllers allegedly support discovering devices by enumerating the twisted pairs in the cable to determine their orientation.

That said, I do not actually know the answer for certain. So, for a connection like this:

```
laptop <---> laptop
```

As opposed to

```
laptop <---> switch <---> laptop
```

Is it necessary to use a special crossover ethernet cable?

Comment: Depends on the specific equipment.  There is no single answer to your question that applies to all situations.

Answer (score 3):

Modern Ethernet connectors and switches (10 years old or newer) detect the proper cable connection called for so crossover cables are not necessary any more.

That said, connecting via a small switch is a much better way to make a connection. Small switches are very inexpensive and can be used in a variety of situations

Comment: I just have one small board computer I need to talk to over the network. And my laptop docking station has an unused ethernet port. But for some reason I can't get the two to communicate. I thought maybe this was it, but also had heard it was no longer necessary.

Comment: You need to look at the network connections and you may need to connect by IP address. Still, if you can manage, a small switch is invaluable

Comment: I assigned the interface an IP address and started DHCP with a range of 1 distinct IP address to lend. Still no connection. A switch would be nice, I just don't have one at the moment.

Comment: Perhaps try static IP addressing for this purpose. It has been a while but that is how I did it back then

Comment: *"But for some reason I can't get the two to communicate."*  -- Then you have posted an XY problem.  You have an answer for your Y question.  Stop asking Y questions, and ask your X question.  BTW a laptop (as in your hypothetical problem) is not a SBC (as in your actual situation/problem).  A PHY chip w/o Auto MDI/MDI-X is more likely on a SBC.